# Converting C++ project from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010 - lib reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can i replace mfcs90.lib with mfcs100.lib  while converting VS2008 project to  VS2010 project

Comment: What is mfcs90.lib? What framework is it for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and should.  Looking around I have found some documentation that may help and explain a bit more about what you need to do.

These MFC link libraries are lightly documented by Microsoft's TN033 Tech Note: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw85e4bb.aspx

A quick summary about the mfcsxxx.lib files is: The MFCSxx[U][D].LIB libraries are used in conjunction with the MFC shared DLLs. These libraries contain code that must be statically linked to the application or DLL.

```
* The "U" designates that the library is built for Unicode.
* The "D" designates that the library is built for Debug.
* If the number in the library is 90, then it's compiled with and for Visual Studio 2008 (VC++ 9.0)
* If the number in the library is 100, then it's compiled with and for Visual Studio 2010 (VC++ 10.0)
```

Note that while the mfcsxxx.lib files have code that is statically linked to the output binary, they are used in conjunction with the DLL versions of MFC - when statically linking MFC, the [nu]afxcw[d].lib libraries are used (where "n" or "u" determines whether or not the library is Unicode, and "d" is used in Debug builds).